# MatLab's strange calculation of an area function

Tags: matlab

I create a function `trapezoidArea` as follow:

```
function area=trapezoidArea(x1,x2,y1,y2)
    area=abs((x2-x1).*(y1+y2))/2; 
end
```

and here is what I have done:

```
t=0:0.1:40;
a(1,1:201)=2;
a(1,201:301)=0;
a(1,301:401)=-4;
t1=t(1:end-1);
t2=t(2:end);
a1=a(1,1:end-1);
a2=a(1,2:end);
v=transpose(trapezoidArea(t1,t2,a1,a2));
```

But interestingly, I get some odd values of `v(200)=0.1000` and `v(300)=0.2000`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love Matlab for its debugging routine. Lets start!

As you shift `a2`from the origin and `a1` from the end you get on the borders such a result. Step by step debugging:

`a1(200)=2,a2(200)=0` and `t1(200)=19.9, t2(200)=20` so `area=0.1*2/2=0.1`

So if you expect to get the same result on the borders you should rearrange your arrays properly.